# Database Process Rollback Design Pattern

Tags: database, oracle, design-patterns, plsql

I am using a database Script (oracle Request) that applies changes to many tables, sometimes I need to rollback the process, and it is a headache to do it manually, so I was thinking to do a custom rollback process, I thought of ways to do it, but I am just asking is there a standard way to implement rollback?, I would appreciate you help.

Comment: You mean other than issuing a `rollback` command? Or is the process committing as it goes, and/or changing table structures (DDL)?

Comment: Yes, the process is committing, plus there maybe lots of changes applied after the script, so rollback command is not an option I think.

Comment: The process does not change tables structures, just insert, delete, update in more than one table.

Comment: Changes are made after the script - do they need to be kept (and what if they're changing something that was already changed by your script), or reverted as well? If you want to get everything back to the state just before the process started then flashback may be an option, but it isn't really clear. What ways have you thought of to do it? And when/why you'd want to revert may be relevant.

Comment: Yes, the after changes need to be kept. If the after changes contradicted with rollback I would like to throw a meaningful exception in that case. Let me explain in more details, say I have some employees, the script should assign a reward for 100 employees, so 100 reward entries are assigned. Then We discovered there is something wrong, I need to delete the elements to fix that, manually is what I am doing now. By then tons of changes have been applied to the system, I cannot delete all that.

Comment: I thought of something like that, After inserting each entry, I will record a delete statement that will delete the same entry in a table, when issuing rollback, all statements in table would be executed.